# How to gain access to some view by id from bridged java class in Apportable?

Tags: java, android, apportable

**This is about `apportable` bridging.**

I have some specific `layout` defined in `main.xml`:

```
<com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

When I try to access to it via standard

`(AdLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.ad_view)`

I get the error:

> error: cannot find symbol
>                       adView = (AdLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
>                                                                  ^   symbol:   variable id   location: class R

So the question is: how I can gain access to this view from bridged Java class?

Comment: have you try after clean project from `Project->Clean`? because as in log `^` is used for views id which is not valid

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK First of all I'm using `Intellij IDEA` for coding `java`. Actually java project itself builds well, there aren't any errors including mentioned piece of code. The error appears when compiling project with apportable utility.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please check in the following places:

```
1. You created this main.xml and this one is included in one of the following value in configuration.json:
```

- "MANIFEST_EXTRAS":"",
- "ACTIVITY_MANIFEST_EXTRAS":"",
- "APPLICATION_MANIFEST_EXTRAS":"",

The xml snippet must be included in the AndroidManifest.xml then it will work.

```
2. If you have made the change in the configuration.json, the next step you may check is the target AndroidManifest.xml, make sure that the main.xml is included in the correct place. If the snippet is not included, you may clean the Build directory of Apportable SDK and redo a load.
```

Hope this information can help you.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I may make a mistake. In this case, you may want to include that xml into the resource. In this case, you can put the name of the xml directory into 'java_res_dirs' in configuration.json.